# Registration Memory - Yamaha PSR S670

Tags: keyboard

I have a Yamaha PSR S670.
I have a problem when I play a song.
When I play a song by choosing an instrument from a Registration Memory, and choose a a style with 100bpm as tempo. When I choose another instrument from a Registration Memory, the speed of style changes, but when I choose any voice from the Voice Buttons it doesn't change tempo.

Is there an issue with Registration Memories?

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't with the Registration Memories, but with what you have saved in them.

Registration Memories are more than just a Voice patch; they can contain
Song
Style
Voice
Multipad
HDR
Harmony
Tempo
Pedal
Text
Slider
Transpose
Scale
Mic Setting &
Line out

You need to decide at Save which of these you want to store in the Registration Memory.

The Voice buttons, simply store Voice patches, so they don't change any other aspect at playback.

Rather than just reading the manual - which are not the easiest things to read - try this guide by Joe Waters - [Understanding Registrations](https://psrtutorial.com/lessons/playing/regist/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use "Freeze" button.. go function.. Freeze...then set which items you want to be frozen.. like transpose, style, tempo etc etc